# AutoFac, NHibernate & ASP.NET Web API integration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4

I've recently been learning (and struggling with) integrating AutoFac, NHibernate & ASP.NET Web API. I have found several tutorials with code that did not work as anticipated but managed to finally find a working solution.

Essentially what I'm doing is registering a singleton of my `SessionFactory` to the `WebApiApplication.SessionFactory` object, registering a per-API-request `ISession` & `IClientRepository`. After these are registered, I'm creating a controller with a DI'ed `IClientRepository` (which in turn has an `ISession` injected which creates a new session as seen in the code below).

My controllers are marked with a custom `TranscationActionFilterAttribute` to bind (or create) a session. The issue I was initially encountering while implementing this pattern is that considering a new session is created every time `IClientRepository` was injected with an `ISession`, the session was never automatically bound and the code in my Transcation action filter would always create an extraneous session, thereby making updates and deletes not function properly. I got around this by binding the `ISession` in the constructor of my `ClientRepository`.

Is this safe?

Global.asax:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var configuration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // Register ISessionFactory as Singleton
        builder.Register(x => NHibernateConfigurator.BuildSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();

        // Register API controller types using assembly scanning.
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                        .Where(t =>
                        !t.IsAbstract && typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(t));

        // Register ISession as instance per web request
        builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InstancePerApiRequest();

        // Register clients controller as instance per web request
        builder.RegisterType<ClientRepository>().As<IClientRepository>().InstancePerApiRequest();

        // Register all controllers
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AsSelf();

        // Override default dependency resolver to use Autofac
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Set the dependency resolver implementation.
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

TransactionAttribute.cs:

```
public class TransactionAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

    public TransactionAttribute()
    {
        SessionFactory = WebApiApplication.SessionFactory;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(SessionFactory))
        {
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
        }

        var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        var transcation = session.Transaction;
        if (transcation != null && transcation.IsActive)
        {
            transcation.Commit();
        }
        session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
        session.Close();
    }
}
```

And the constructor for my repository:

```
    public ClientRepository(ISession session) 
    {
        if (session == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("nhSession");
        this._session = session;
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_session);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to answer your question directly but..

> By definition I suppose that Code Review allows me to suggest and
>   share subjective ideas (to be determined)...

By convention, stuff that needs to be done on the application start can be located in a App_Start folder.

Here's a template for AutoFac, `~/App_Start/AutofacMvcConfig.cs`:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;
using Models;
using MvcApplication.App_Start;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AutofacMvcConfig), "Start")]

namespace MvcApplication.App_Start
{
    public class AutofacMvcConfig
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterType<TodoCommands>().As<ITodoCommands>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<TodoQueries>().As<ITodoQueries>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            // Install-Package Autofac.Mvc3
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
}
```

### Readings

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335350/unitofwork-in-action-filter-seems-to-be-caching
- http://jittuu.com/2012/2/9/UnitOfWork-pattern-and-asp.net-mvc/
- http://slynetblog.blogspot.ca/2012/03/using-aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-with.html
- http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/yet-another-session-per-request-post

Keywords: mvc, unit of work, autofac, actionfilterattribute